# Object not set to an instance on OnPause()

Tags: xamarin

I get '**Object not set to an instance**' error on my App every time my App request permission to access READ_PHONE_STATE and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in OnPause() method. I didn't write code to request permission, the App request permission automatically.

As soon as the permission dialog shows up, OnPause() method gets triggered and the error occurs on this line : base.OnPause();

```
protected override void OnPause()
{
     base.OnPause(); //error occurs here
}
```

How can i solve this issue ? 
What's the best method of requesting all the relevant permissions ? And how can I you handle this method in OnResume() and OnPause() methods.

Comment: why are you requesting permissions in OnPause?

Comment: have you tried adding those permissions to the manifest file? There might be some plugins which requires those permissions.

Comment: I finaly found the issue. The problem was caching on my phone. Clicking Ctrl + F5, forced the Application to clear all the cache. Rebuild didn't work. After clicking Ctrl + F5, the permission dialogs showed without triggering the OnPause function, and object not set to an instance error message disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue. The problem was caching on my phone. Clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, forced the Application to clear all the cache. Rebuild didn't work. After clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, the permission dialogs showed without triggering the OnPause function - and object not set to an instance error message disappeared.